# Как установить модули для grunt не локально?

Tags: node.js, grunt

Как установить модули node js не локально или указать путь к ним в grunt?
Мне нужно, чтобы в папке проекта не лежали тяжелые модули node js, они занимают место, мешают поиску в папке и.т.д.

Comment: а не глобально как устанавливаете?

Comment: npm install -g yourmodule. На винде они при этом встанут в user/AppData/Roaming/npm

Comment: сейчас захожу в папку cd "папка проекта"
дальше команды 

npm install grunt-contrib-concat

И он ставит в мою проекта парку в папку node_modules этот модуль grunt-contrib-concat

"project/node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat"

Comment: ну там везде пишут, что ставить модули глобально это дурной тон и это не должно поддерживаться в новых версиях.

Comment: Ну это, Вы хотите не локально, не локально - это глобально)

Comment: Я поставил глобально он всё равно пишет 

>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-concat" not found. Is it installed?

Comment: А, все понял, ваша проблема в том, как указать гранту на node_modules в другой папке. Можно симлинк сделать из папки проекта на реальную папку с node_modules.
Вот: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Comment: Вы тратите свое время не на те вещи. Вместо того, чтобы пытаться лепить костыли с глобальной установкой модулей, которые должны устанавливаться локально, лучше настройте свою IDE, чтобы `node_modules` "не мешало поиску в папке".

Comment: зачем мне эти файлы локально то в папке? В чем их смысл, мне просто нужен сборщик и всё, а не куча лишних файлов в папках моих проектов.

Comment: @ru_volt
А как это указать то? Я с такой техникой не знаком, можете объяснить подробно что это?

Comment: @manking: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0
Ссылку как это ставить прям средствами npm я выше кинул. 
Я потому и пишу комментарий, а не полноценный ответ, что мне лень вам сейчас доки переводить. Вот щас найдется какая-нибудь добрая душа которая это сделает и срубит свой заслуженный плюсик. Кстати я как и Дмитрий добавляю просто node_modules в exclude в IDE

Comment: @manking, вам эти файлы чем-то мешают? Ну и потом, все **сборочные** зависимости вы должны добавлять в `devDependencies`, один раз собирать проект, а после деплоя _не устанавливать_ сборочные/тестовые пакеты: `npm i --production`. В целом я все-равно не вижу причин изобретать костыли

Comment: Ну как диск захламляется всяким мусором, я их даже удалить спокойно не могу эти файлы, у них имена слишком длинные чтобы поместить в корзину. А если проектов много, то в каждом будет такой мусор одинаковый, куча файлов и весит много и архивировать сложно всё это. Я не вижу каких то плюсов здесь для сборщика проектов в этой архитектуре.

Comment: 1. Жесткие диски (да и вообще постоянная память) сейчас настолько дешевы, что вопрос о "захломлении диска" считаю абсурдным. 2. Корзина не нужна. Совсем. 3. Не надо ничего архивировать. Все, что находится в каталоге `node_modules` **не является** частью вашего проекта. Это внешние зависимости. Просто не добавляйте их в архив. 4. (в дополнение к 2. и 3.) - вы, похоже не можете построить нормальный рабочий процесс. Вместо всей этой возни с корзиной и архивами разверните обычный VCS, пометив каталог `node_modules`, как исключенный из репозитория.